# shell curl https://api.cai.tools.sap/build/v1/dialog doesn't automatically create conversation. Returns 404 "Resource not found"

Tags: curl, sap-conversational-ai

if I send request like here https://cai.tools.sap/docs/api-reference/#dialog-endpoints with my own REQUEST_TOKEN and generated on my side CONVERSATION_ID, e.g. example-com-test-1, the 404 error returns.

My bot has private status, and has no integrations with any plaform. Is it possible to connect to my bot via api or I've missed something?

Example is

```sh
curl -H "Authorization: Token REQUEST_TOKEN" \
     -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
     -d '{"message": {"content":"Hi there! How are you?","type":"text"}, "conversation_id": "CONVERSATION_ID"}' \
     -X POST "https://api.cai.tools.sap/build/v1/dialog"
```

Answer (score 0):

This CURL works on my end, are you sure you used the right request token from your version? Also conversation ID needs to be between quotes.